# Jquery <br> in html causing consecutive text nodes during unwrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Consider my three parts of code

```
<div>
Lorem Ispum dolor sit <span class='highlightYellow'>Amet </span>
<br />Lorem  Ispum <span class='highlightYellow'>dolor</span> sit Amet
</div>

<div>
Lorem Ispum dolor sit <span class='highlightYellow'>Amet </span>
Lorem  Ispum <span class='highlightYellow'>dolor</span> sit Amet
<br />
</div>

<div>
Lorem Ispum dolor sit <span class='highlightYellow'>Amet </span>
Lorem  Ispum <span class='highlightYellow'>dolor</span> sit Amet
</div>
```

and a button

```
<button>Unwrap text from .hightlightYellow elements</button>
```

I'm using this method to unwrap

```
$(".highlightYellow").contents().unwrap();
```

When see the childnodes of `<div>`, by something like `$('div')[i].childNodes` due to the `<br/>` tag, the contents within the div becomes multiple consecutive text nodes. how two texnodes come one after another? It is really impossible. But here it comes.

In the third `<div>`, there is no `<br/>` tag. So it is working fine. I guessed the `<br/>` tag only causes this issue. Or is there any other method to overcome this?

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R4hfa/29/), you can see the issues by inspecting element

Comment: Why there can not be two text nodes one by another? http://jsfiddle.net/zmnggf3b/

Comment: I didn't get. You have `n` nodes inside your `div`. When you unwrap element nodes, it's become just a `n` text nodes. What is wrong here?

Comment: How two consecutive textnodes come?

Comment: @LeshaOgonkov two text nodes inside `<div>` instead of desired one.

Comment: @Cheery if two consecutive textnodes come, they ll be merged into one

Comment: @ling.s look at my fiddle - do they merge?

Comment: If you have one text node and one element node, when you remove element and replace it with text it becomes two text nodes. Why not?

Comment: @ling.s are you sure?? http://jsfiddle.net/zmnggf3b/1/

Comment: For me all unwrapped nodes become text nodes (Chrome on Ubuntu)

Comment: @Cheery saw that. This is abnormal behaviour...

Comment: @ling.s Why? You are operating with DOM, not with html code. Who said that they should merge ?)) When you operate with html, then the whole text is one text node after conversion into DOM structure.

Comment: A text node cannot have children and its previous and next siblings can't be another text

Comment: @ling.s Do you have it in RFC or any other standard?

Comment: In RFC. `All consecutive characters are placed into a single textnode`

Comment: @Cheery, If so, then why the 3rd type works correctly? Only one text node is there. As per your words, it should show multiple text nodes. why it couldn't?

Comment: @ling.s I see 5 text nodes in the 3rd type. Look at picture, every node is in quotes http://oi62.tinypic.com/20l5x1.jpg

Comment: It's a good question. But I think the issue is not effect page view, don't I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-1312295772

> When a document is first made available via the DOM, there is only one
>   Text node for each block of text. **Users may create adjacent Text nodes
>   that represent the contents of a given element without any intervening
>   markup, but should be aware that there is no way to represent the
>   separations between these nodes in XML or HTML, so they will not (in
>   general) persist between DOM editing sessions.** The normalize() method
>   on Element merges any such adjacent Text objects into a single node
>   for each block of text; this is recommended before employing
>   operations that depend on a particular document structure, such as
>   navigation with XPointers.

```
$('div').each(function(i, element) {
    element.normalize(); 
   //The normalize() method removes empty Text nodes, and joins adjacent Text nodes.
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qv34tof4/1/)

Comment: So should I use normalize() method?

Comment: @ling.s yes, you should if you want to merge them

Comment: Woo, i didn't knew about that method. I have add code example with your help.

Comment: will check and let you know

Comment: @ling.s Lesha added example to my answer. ps: спасибо, Алексей )

Comment: @Cheery http://jsfiddle.net/qv34tof4/2/ How does it make a difference? Should I use something other than .contents?